# Let $S$ be the non-positive real axis. Let $U=C -S$. Show $\exists f:U -> C$ such that $f(z)^2 = z$ for all $z\in U$ using analyticity of $\frac 1z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for the poorly formatted title, but I hit the 150 char limit. To reiterate:

Let $U$ be the complex plane with the non-positive real axis deleted. We see that $\frac 1 z$ is holomorphic on $U$. I am supposed to use this fact to prove that there exists a function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $f(z)^2 = z$ for all $z\in z$.

I don't understand why I am using $\frac 1 z$. Given $z = re^{i\theta}$, I can just define $f(z) = \sqrt r e^{\frac {i\theta}2}$. The question has no restriction of what $f$ can be, only that it is a function, and clearly $f$ is a function satisfying $f(z)^2 = z$.

I had another train of thought that I'm not sure is leading anywhere: $f(z)^2 = z$ is equivalent to $f(z)^2 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}}$, so if we denote $z\mapsto \frac 1z$ by $g$ then we want to find $f$ such that $f^2 = g\circ g$. This seems better, because now at least we know $f^2$ is holomorphic. But now I don't see what to do without just taking the principal root.

Comment: You'd still need to show that your $\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$ is holomorphic (I suppose the exercise asks for a holomorphic square root). That's not particularly difficult. The intended way is to deduce that a logarithm exists on $U$, and then $z\mapsto \exp \bigl(\frac{1}{k}\log z\bigr)$ defines a $k^{\text{th}}$ root (the exercise looks at $k = 2$).

Comment: Interestingly, the exercise does not explicitly ask for a holomorphic function, but I agree with you in that it probably is supposed to. Thank you for the hint.